# htaccess not working on windows server 2003 with apache installed

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, windows-server-2003

I have Apache installed.

I have `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` un-commented and set every instance of `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` in http.conf.

My site is in a subfolder, so its like `http://123.34.56.123/Website/` to get to it.

*.htaccess file*

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /Website/ 
Options +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteRule ^index.php http://www.google.com/? [R=301,L]
```

But when I visit the above address, it does not redirect to google.com and, instead, shows the contents of index.php.

Update:

Added junk to the .htaccess file and http.conf to force a internal server error, and it still just goes to my index.php.

Did a var dump on `$_SERVER`, and found this out: `["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]=> string(17) "Microsoft-IIS/6.0"`, but can't find any program files around IIS.

Comment: What folder is the `.htaccess` file in? Also, just a hunch: you call it an "htaccess file" repeatedly in your post. The filename *must* be `.htaccess`. Can you confirm it is named correctly?

Comment: If this is a brand new install -- A common windows problem is editing httpd.conf as a non-administrator, and windows creates a shadow copy of it for the non-administrator -- httpd continues to use the real file.  A quick test is appending "fdsfsfsfs" and seeing if it breaks Apache.

Comment: @covener Hm, so I edited the http.conf file by appending junk to it, and it didn't break Apache. You've put me on a new path, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, some probable causes of your problem:

- Incorrectly named `.htaccess` file. You call it an "htaccess file" repeatedly in your post. The filename *must* be `.htaccess` (with the leading `.`).
- File in the wrong directory. Make sure this file is in the root directory of your site.
- The module you need to enable isn't `mod_userdir.so`, but `mod_rewrite.so`. Look for a line like this one: `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`
- Make sure the `[R=301,L]` is on the same line as the `RewriteRule` to which it applies, or you will have errors.

Also, don't do a `301` on this, even for testing -- it will permanently redirect traffic to your `index.php` to Google. That's what a 301 does. For testing, use a `302`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and mistakes on my part. It is named `.htaccess` and in the root of my website in `/Website/`. The module enabled is also correct, and I fixed my post to reflect that. Also, the RewriteRule is on the same line as the flags, [R=301,L] -- which was a result of someone's typo when they edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Converting comment to an answer, if your update to httpd.conf mysteriously fail to change anything on Windows, edit httpd.conf as Administrator (not a member of the  administrator group, Administrator) to avoid Windows silently doing "data redirection" of httpd.conf edited out of Program Files.

http://blogs.windows.com/windows/archive/b/developers/archive/2009/08/04/user-account-control-data-redirection.aspx